# How to set Jenkins variable from plugin (Builder)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am banging my head on the table.  The Jenkins plugin documentation is terrible and the examples I found in the Git Plugin to set "GIT_URL" works but mine doesn't?

`build.getEnvironment(getListener()).put("FOO", "bar");`

No other build tasks can see this!

Comment: getListener() what is actually performing. here

Comment: It is the listener that is passed into `perform()`

Comment: Have you tried:
build.addAction(new ParametersAction(new StringParameterValue("FOO", "bar")))

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?
Jenkins allows you to specify build parameters, which can have default values.
Build parameters are referred to as environment variables within your Jenkins job.

There should be an option to say your build is parameterized.  Enabling that will allow you to create build parameters.

Comment: I don't follow, I am in a plugin and want to set a variable that another buildstep can use similar to GitPlugin.  I don't want to set them from the console or configuration.